# Save or Export Excel as csv with commas in cell values

Tags: excel, csv, data-conversion

My Excel has a block with a comma `,` eg. `abcd,xyz`.

When I convert this Excel to CSV, this text gets converted as 2 columns.

Can anyone advise how I can prevent this?

Comment: use another delimiter or put your textblock in quotes

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Excel by default will use a comma as the delimiter, but you can change that:

1. Go to Control Panel > "Region and Language" (Or just "Region" in Windows 10), and then click the **"Additional settings"** button on the bottom.
2. Now look very closely at the **List separator** item, which normally
   has a **comma** in the field, and for the purposes of this illustration,
   change it to a Pipe `|` character.
3. Once you hit Apply, and then save your Excel file as a CSV file, you’ll notice that your file now has pipe `|` characters as the delimiter.

PS: You'll probably want to change the List separator back to a comma just in case some other application needs it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Koby for your response but I don't want to change my server configuration for the very reason you have mentioned. Any other way of handling this as I want (,) to be my separator only.